# How does RestEasy YAML support work?

Tags: java, rest, yaml, resteasy

I've managed to configure RESTEasy to use YAML, or I think I've done that. 
After struggling with the documentation, thanks to help from the mail lists, I've included the right dependencies in my pom file.

However, I am now getting

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: 
No JavaBean properties found  in 
uk.ac.ucl.chime.bosphorus.messages.ArchetypesList
```

When I try to call a method that returns an ArchetypeList instance, which is only a container for a List. RestEasy works for XML and JSON serialization on this class and others, by only changing the java annotations, so XML and JSON works out of the box for JAXB annotations.

I would assume YAML to work the same way, but I think I am wrong. There is no example of YAML support working, though it seems to have been reported working. The underlying SnakeYAML library used by RestEasy does not seem to support annotations indeed, but I'd expect RestEasy to deal with that, at least to provide support for YAML consistent with the way it does with JSON or XML.

Have you used YAML with resteasy before? How is it supposed to work?